# PayStub - What is Employee ID?

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs, payroll-taxes, income-tax-refund

Would anyone be so kind to please explain what is Employee ID and where can I get this information online on my own? The term "on my own" means that I want to find this myself without asking/calling/emailing employer. I thought Employee ID is EIN but it seems like this is not true. The EIN looks like "12-3456789" but what I see on PayStub the "Employee ID", whatever this is, could be fewer digits, sometimes four digits, sometimes five, something just three etc. So what is Employee ID and where can I get this for particular employer on my own? I don't have any records of past taxes so impossible to check historically - I need direct info where to get this. Thank you!

Comment: It's probably whatever the company uses internally in its Human Resources software, so (short of hacking into the company's systems) you'd be unlikely to find it on your own.  (I've worked for a company where my Employee ID was 3, and others where it was 6 or 7 digits.)

Comment: If you don't have record of it, and it's an ID they created, then there seems no way to get it without asking them.

Comment: What do you need it for, and why are you unwilling to ask the employer for it? I suspect you _actually_ need something different than an employee ID (since you tagged income_tax_refund), which would be proprietary to that company.

Comment: @DStanley Can't speak for the US, but in the UK the employer-assigned number ("_Employer PAYE Reference_") _is_ passed to HMRC (equivalent of IRS) when an employer reports salary payments. Probably not critical most of the time, as your National Insurance number (=SSN) identifies "you"; may be needed if you have more than one job.

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes. This is a legit question, and Aganju has the correct answer.

Answer (score 6):

*Employee ID* is the number or code your company uses to identify you uniquely.
Its format is completely up to the employer, and it has no meaning outside of this employer.